# Changed LC_ALL does not display unicode charaters

Tags: command-line

I exported the following enviromental variables to change my terminal language with the following values:

```
LC_ALL=C
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

But now when I type a commang such as:

```
apksigner
```

I get the following output:

```
apksigner: \u03b7 \u03b5\u03bd\u03c4\u03bf\u03bb\u03ae \u03b4\u03b5 \u03b2\u03c1\u03ad\u03b8\u03b7\u03ba\u03b5
```

How can I display unicode characters to my terminal whilst I want to maintain the graphical UI is in different language (eg. Greek in my case)?

Comment: `LC_ALL=C.UTF-8`, maybe?

Comment: still my terminal output is in greek